# Installing Ubuntu alongside windows 10 or with separate partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on the SSD that has my windows 10, I have put a 20GB for my Linux OS I think this size would be enough because I don't want to do a lot of work in Linux, install a lot of program .. etc.

I just want to test couple stuff about USB communication issues I got in windows 10.

The installation provides 3 options:

1. Install alongside windows 10
2. Erase and install Ubuntu
3. Something else.

===========================================================================================

1. I wanted to install with option 1, but it mentioned something that Linux would change the rooting system or would do some modification in the root system.

My question about this point, is it a problem in future if I wanted to uninstall Ubuntu ? Or I better go with option 3 ?

2. Option 3 that I provided a 20GB for it, I learned about swap, so I don't need it because I have 16GB RAM, that is plenty for Windows 10 so I think it would be the same for Linux.

So I have to just select the 20GB and select the + then do like this:

[image]

So with this arrangement, it would work like option 1, right ?

Comment: Will work, but I would like a bit  more space.  If just for testing can use the 'Try Ubuntu' option on USB and will not need to install.  It will not keep any changes unless you make it have the persistence feature.  Option 1 and 3 will do the same type of install, including adding grub to choose OSs.  Option 3 gives you more control on sizes.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks, my whole goal now is to test some stuff about usb connection and I want to install some programs for programming microcontrollers. So I think I need to install it. I tried option 3, but it gave me an error message that there's a problem that the partition doesn't have the root requirement I guess.

Comment: Your picture looks good, you have it mounted as root.  The only problem would be if Windows and Ubuntu were not installed the same.  Both using UEFI and GPT, or legacy and MBR type partition tables.  Is this an older Win 7 computer upgraded to Win 10 or a Win 8 or 10 computer?

Comment: Can change it to primary instead of logical, but that is only thing I see.  Can have many primary on a GPT drive, but only four on a MBR drive.

Comment: @crip659 I chose logical as I learned from a YouTube video and mount point as `/`. It worked well and the installation started. Then Ubuntu asked for a restarted and I went ahead to changed boot to windows boot manager as I couldn't find Ubuntu. I didn't know how to launch Ubuntu from boot menu.

Comment: OK, I installed Ubuntu, had to change boot option to Ubuntu #1 then windows #2. Also I disabled the basic 4 boot priorities I don't know if that is necessary but anyway I booted into Ubuntu. It's a bit slow, I expect it to be a snappy thing like windows but anyway I just need to test some stuff and then go back to windows for God's will.